# Phonegap Android - fileSystem.root is NULL

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems, phonegap-plugins

```
I have installed couple of working plugins but unable to work on the FILE plugin. The problem i am facing is that the fileSystem.root returns as NULL as a result of which i cannot proceed further. The example i have picked is from the phonegap site for the plugin. I haven'yt done any change to the same. I am getting the OnDeviceReady logs.

Index.html:

   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileReader Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="json2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for Cordova to load

    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        console.log("onDeviceReady");
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        console.log(fileSystem.root.name);
        console.log(fileSystem.name);
        console.log(fileSystem.root.fullpath);

        fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", null, gotFileEntry, fail);
    }


    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        console.log("fileEntry");
        fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);
    }

    function gotFile(file){
        console.log("gotFile");
        readDataUrl(file);
        readAsText(file);
    }

    function readDataUrl(file) {
        console.log("readDataUrl");
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as data URL");
            console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            console.log("Read as text");
            //console.log(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function fail(evt) {
        //console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        console.log("FAIL");
    }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Example</h1>
    <p>Read File</p>
  </body>
</html>


Logs:

08-03 08:38:18.730: D/CordovaLog(28552): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 17 : onDeviceReady
08-03 08:38:18.740: I/Web Console(28552): onDeviceReady at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:17
08-03 08:38:18.760: I/Web Console(28552): null at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:22
08-03 08:38:18.760: D/CordovaLog(28552): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 23 : persistent
08-03 08:38:18.760: I/Web Console(28552): persistent at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:23
08-03 08:38:18.760: D/CordovaLog(28552): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 24 : undefined
08-03 08:38:18.760: I/Web Console(28552): undefined at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:24
08-03 08:38:18.760: W/System.err(28552): java.io.FileNotFoundException: path does not exist
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at org.apache.cordova.file.LocalFilesystem.getFileForLocalURL(LocalFilesystem.java:194)
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.getFile(FileUtils.java:757)
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils.access$6(FileUtils.java:750)
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$17.run(FileUtils.java:405)
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils$24.run(FileUtils.java:533)
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
08-03 08:38:18.790: W/System.err(28552):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
08-03 08:38:18.800: D/CordovaLog(28552): file:///android_asset/www/index.html: Line 62 : FAIL
08-03 08:38:18.800: I/Web Console(28552): FAIL at file:///android_asset/www/index.html:62
```

The fileSystem.name is persistent or temporary(depending on the parameter i set), but the root and all other parameters are NULL so i cannot do anything further.

I have searched a lot in the documentation and on previous posts but unable to solve the bug. I install the plugin using the cordova plugin add utility which sets all permissions/config etc.

Please help me with the same.
PS(I am directly working on the Sony Xperia Device with android 4.3).

Comment: `fileSystem.root` is null and does not have the getFile function? so neither `gotFileEntry` or `fail` are called? Are you able to share your whole index.html?

Comment: I have shared the full Index.html along with the logs where the error is coming right after receiving device Ready. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/

This may help :
second parameter is  size  : Size (in bytes) the app will require for storage.

```
function onInitFs(fs) {
  console.log('Opened file system: ' + fs.name);
}

window.requestFileSystem(window.TEMPORARY, 5*1024*1024 /*5MB*/, onInitFs, errorHandler);
```

Comment: what does not work? Just do not make a blanket statement. You need to give us error/issue/problems in DETAIL, then only we will be able to help you out.

Comment: Frank i meant that the behavior is same with this code change. I have updated the code and provided full logs. Please let me know if you need any further information. Thanks.

Comment: Size is not required for the Cordova file plugin when calling `requestFileSystem` - it is standard to pass 0. It only exists to more closely match the HTML5 File API arguments but it is not the same implementation.